# Calculation with QUARTILES in DAX

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I need a help with the calculation of quartiles in DAX.

I have create an excel formula whihc is the correct answer and i am trying to find out the way to build this fomrula to Power Bi.

This is the DAX code which i have right until now but the result is wrong.

```
T/B = VAR SelectedUnit=[Stated Success]
VAR p0 = PERCENTILEX.INC(ALLSELECTED(Data[Creator name trim]),[Stated Success],0)
VAR p25 = PERCENTILEX.INC(ALLSELECTED(Data[Creator name trim]),[Stated Success],0.25)
VAR p50 =PERCENTILEX.INC(ALLSELECTED(Data[Creator name trim]),[Stated Success],0.5)
VAR p75 =PERCENTILEX.INC(ALLSELECTED(Data[Creator name trim]),[Stated Success],0.75)
RETURN
IF([Stated Success]=BLANK(),BLANK(),SWITCH(ISFILTERED(Data[Creator name trim]),
SelectedUnit>p75,"T",
SelectedUnit>=p50,"MT",
SelectedUnit>=p25,"ML","B"))
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Try to split your DAX expression, and check if you get the correct value for each VAR;
Stated Success is a Column or Measure?

Comment: It's a measure.